# webhdfs is redirecting to localhost:50075

Tags: hadoop, webhdfs

I am trying to create a file from a non-hadoop environment to a remote hdfs.
For this purpose, I am using pywebhdfs api and I'm running command using curl.
https://pythonhosted.org/pywebhdfs/

I used this documentation as a reference, I am able to execute all other methods except of **create_file()**.

While using **create_file()**, I am getting error like: ***'Couldn't connect to host'***

**Command**: curl -i -X PUT -L "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:50070/webhdfs/v1/test1/?op=CREATE" -T sample.txt

**Response**:HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 307 TEMPORARY_REDIRECT
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Tue, 30 Oct 2018 12:04:04 GMT
Date: Tue, 30 Oct 2018 12:04:04 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Tue, 30 Oct 2018 12:04:04 GMT
Date: Tue, 30 Oct 2018 12:04:04 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
**Location**: http://**localhost**:50075/webhdfs/v1/test1/?op=CREATE&namenoderpcaddress=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9000&overwrite=false
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(6.1.26)

curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

This **Location** is displaying as localhost here. I took reference from the past post.

[webhdfs always redirect to localhost:50075](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34012135/webhdfs-always-redirect-to-localhost50075)

but I didn't get success.

I tried changing IP in **hdfs-site.xml** and **/etc/hosts** file but no success at all.

Can anyone tell me, how to fix this?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Can you post the content of your /etc/hosts

Comment: What did you change in the hdfs-site?

Comment: Problem is solved, problem was with **/etc/hosts** file only. I changed it like **127.0.0.1   <datanode IP>     localhost**